# Return the count of posts where meta value is equal to

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've created a custom field by using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. This field is called status and by default is equal upcoming and then it will be changed to either correct or wrong later.

I'm then trying to query all the posts where the status meta value is equal to either correct or wrong. However even though i've set this in the below Query it still return the count of all posts. I've double checked and counted how many posts there are equal to correct or wrong and still i get the wrong count. What am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT posts.ID) as count, AVG(odds.meta_value) as ave
  FROM $wpdb->posts posts
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta stat
             ON posts.ID = stat.post_id
            AND stat.meta_key = 'status'
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta odds
             ON posts.ID = odds.post_id
            AND odds.meta_key = 'odds'
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr ON posts.ID = tr.object_id
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id 
  WHERE stat.meta_value    = 'wrong'
   OR stat.meta_value    = 'correct'
   AND posts.post_status      = 'publish'
   AND t.taxonomy = 'category'
   AND t.term_id  = 4
   OR t.term_id  = 5
   OR t.term_id  = 6
```

Comment: Change your WHERE to AND,also you might want some parentheses in those AND or OR conditions..

Comment: Then it returns 115 which is way above the actual posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use brackets to group together what should be together:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT posts.ID) as count, AVG(odds.meta_value) as ave
FROM $wpdb->posts posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta stat
    ON posts.ID = stat.post_id
    AND stat.meta_key = 'status'
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta odds
    ON posts.ID = odds.post_id
    AND odds.meta_key = 'odds'
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr
    ON posts.ID = tr.object_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy t
    ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id 
WHERE (stat.meta_value    = 'wrong'
   OR stat.meta_value    = 'correct')
   AND posts.post_status      = 'publish'
   AND t.taxonomy = 'category'
   AND (t.term_id  = 4
   OR t.term_id  = 5
   OR t.term_id  = 6)
```